# Partition of windows causing problem after installing and not shown in grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

I recently installed windows 7 to my computer.
After installation my ubuntu partition was converted into unallocated space.
used testdisk to recover it.
After that i ran boot-repair recommended repair.
On rebooting, grub didn't show the option of windows 7. Here below are screenshots of gparted.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: From a Windows repairCD or flash drive run chkdsk on the NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal session ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type the following command :

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Reboot the system. Windows must have appeared in the grub menu now.

Comment: Because of the issues of the NTFS partition the Linux NTFS driver will not mount it and then grub2's os-prober will not be able to read it and find the Windows boot files.